# Calling a VB.net function from Java

Tags: java, vb.net, printing, jna

How can I call a VB.net function in Java? I tried doing this in Java:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallFunctionMapper;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class Main2{
public interface Class1 extends StdCallLibrary
{
    void fn_Today(int a,int b);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Map options = new HashMap();
        options.put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, new StdCallFunctionMapper()) ;
        Class1 INSTANCE = (Class1) Native.loadLibrary("fn_Today", Class1.class, options);
    INSTANCE.fn_Today(0, 0);
}
```

}

But it returned this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5xGZ.png)

My Code in VB.Net:

```
Public Class TestClass
Public Function SumNum(Val1 As Integer, Val2 As Integer)
    Dim TVal As Integer
    TVal = Val1 + Val2

    Return TVal

End Function
End Class
```

Comment: JNA can access functions exported from a shared library which supports standard "C" calling conventions and symbol export.  If you can't modify your VB.Net build to support that, JNA won't be of any use.

Comment: @technomage How can I modify my VB.net which it can be supported by the JNA?

Comment: You can enable [COM interop](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/create-dll.html), but that's probably overkill for your case.  You need to figure out how to generate a C-compatible DLL from within your project's options (whether visual studio or command-line).